# How to delete record in a table and in its sub-table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to create a link to delete a record and it's sub record in a foreign table.
My models are like this :

```
class Cv < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :formation
end

class Formation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :cv
  validates :cv_id, presence: true
end
```

in my index view I have :

```
<%- @cv.each do |p| -%>
          <%= link_to p.nom, cvsindex2_path(p) %>
          <%= link_to 'delete', cvsdestroy_path(p) %></br>
<%- end -%>
```

My route :

```
 cvsdestroy DELETE /cvs/:id(.:format)
```

How can I do that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: sub record in a foreign table? Do you mean associated record?

Comment: Yes i mean that. i have foreign key in my formation table

Comment: Can you post your routes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you will add dependent destroy to your relationship it will delete all its associated records from foreign key tables also.

```
class Cv < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :formation, dependent: destroy
end
```

Comment: thank you but does my link to delete correct? and wich detroy method use? please

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `dependent: :destroy` to your `formation` model in order to delete the associated record.

```
class Formation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :cv, dependent: :destroy
  validates :cv_id, presence: true
end
```

And also change ***formation*** to ***formations*** in your `cv` model as you have `has_many` relation.

***Update***

You should also change your ***Delete*** link to like this

```
<%= link_to 'delete', cvsdestroy_path(p), method: :delete %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you that work with this

```
<%= link_to 'delete', @cv, :data => {:confirm => 'Are you sure?'}, :method => :delete %>
```

and

```
def destroy
    @cvdestroy = Cv.find(params[:id])
    @cvdestroy.destroy
    redirect_to cvs_path, :notice => "Your CV has been deleted"
end
```